# Can't seem to play this chord on fingerstyle

Tags: chords

I've been trying to get my fingers to play this chord (you have to pluck all of them at once) but it's just not working out.

[image]

My pinky doesn't reach all the way to the fourth fret when I put my other fingers down (Pointer on Lowest E, Middle on the G string, and the Ring finger on the Highest E)

Am I just fingering it wrong?

Comment: it's always worth trying out different fingerings. Or different shapes/voicings for the same chord. Here, it's B7/F#. An open version is not too difficult, and will sound *nearly* the same. 221202. Or 201202.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much easier to play it as a barre chord: use your index finger on all strings on the 2nd fret, and another fingertip for the 4th fret.

Wiki has a page on this subject [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barre_chord)

Comment: Might help to acquire a slide for this, I know my index finger is not built for doing barre chords properly without one. (One string always passes through the gap between the knuckles and sounds mushy.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it all comes to practice.. don't fret **pun intended** if at first your barres do not sound as good as the professionals have it. Just keep doing it and one day you'll get it right and it will just be muscle memory.

Answer (score 4):

I wrap my left thumb around the neck, so that is how I would play it.  Most people will reject the whole concept.  But consider - I don't have to play the six note barred F chord!

Comment: That's how Hendrix would play it I'm guessing

Comment: +1 Wrapping round the thumb is how I've always seen it played. Unfortunately some people's hands just aren't big enough. You won't find this in classical repertoire, partly because classical/nylon stringed necks are wider than steel stringed ones.

Answer (score 0):

Thumb on the sixth (and fifth) string. Then you can use you third finger on the fourth string for a proper Dom 7th chord, just like Travis.